# Яндекс Карты получить геокоординаты

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Есть ли в Яндекс картах встроенная возможность получения координат в виде часов минут и секунд? И если есть, то как?

Версия API 2.1

Answer (score 1):

Подумав решил, что во "встроенных" функциях нет необходимости, есть они там или нет.

Для достяжения желаемого результата, использую следующую код:

```
        function toAngle(coord){
            var sec = Math.round(coord * 3600);
            var deg = (sec / 3600).toString().substring(0,2);
            sec = Math.abs(sec % 3600);
            var min = ((sec / 60).toString() + "0").substring(0,2);
            sec %= 60;
            sec = (sec.toString() + "0").substring(0,2);

            return deg+"°"+min+"′"+sec+"″";
        }
```